# update woocommere total value on checkout based on selected payment method

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

i have 2 payment methods .. in one of them i add extra fees 
How to trigger WooCommerce Ajax which updates shipping calculation on change payment method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved using jQuery

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).on('change','#payment',function(){
    jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
   });

});
```